# megatree for hydro / src, wiki outdated

Tags: ros, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed and tested megatree (http://wiki.ros.org/megatree/Tutorials/GettingStarted) on my system using my old fuerte installation and it works quite impressive.

I'd like to develop some application on top of it. My entire ros related work is in hydro, though, i. e. I'd need a hydro release of megatree in order for embedding it. The mentioned link still is at fuerte. I considered porting the src myself to hydro but the source link in the wiki still links me to kforge.ros.org, i. e. is no longer available. Does anyone know whether there is a github repo to which megatree has moved?

Edit Mar, 14: Anyone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125621/megatree-for-hydro-/-src,-wiki-outdated/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've dug up a copy from my archives it's not available on github at: https://github.com/ros-perception/megatree

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1